# 404 Code Igniter on a live web server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've tried change my .htaccess file many times on my server (Linux, php CGI/FastCGI)

My web hosting is a reseller hosting and i have both panels the CP and WHM

But when i upload my entire website i only receive 404 errors and follow my config,htaccess and controller files and the folder structure

Folder Structure

```
/
index.php
/application/
/application/views [Contains main view (index page)]
/application/controllers [Contains the main controller]
```

As the default from Code Igniter (3.0)

.htaccess file [First time]

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

.htaccess file [Second Time]

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|fonts|img|css|js|dashboard|support|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Config file

```
$config['base_url'] = '/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Error Log

```
ERROR - 2015-02-06 14:53:34 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
ERROR - 2015-02-06 14:53:35 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
ERROR - 2015-02-06 14:54:01 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
```

i tried to change URI Protocol to all options possible in the CI, changed the htaccess, deleted the access.

For now nothing worked for me

My base url site is http://pixelvision.com.br/

The website works wells on my local webserver (Easy PHP Dev/Production)
And dont return any error when is running on my local web server.

But when i send the entire website (update the config files) and try to run return for all controllers the 404 error

Comment: Shouldn't "http://pixelvision.com.br/" be your BASE_URL?

Comment: @Craig i've tried and still the 404 changed the BASE_URL to 'pixelvision.com.br/' as you asked and dind't worked

Comment: You had the "http://" too?

Comment: @Craig yes. http, https, www

Comment: Is your hosted server a Windows server? Or Linux?

Comment: @Craig CLOUDLINUX 6.6 x86_64 standard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution for who uses Code Igniter 3.0 the controller name needs to be like this "Pagecontrol" if is "pagecontrol" the CodeIgniter core do not find the controller, libraries, views, and things like this.

Comment: I don't understand why it work on my localhost with lowercase and on live server it demand uppercase.?

Comment: I'll search a reason for this and i'll post for you

Comment: @Darknessxk ever find that reason? having same issue

Comment: @SpYk3HH The problem is located within one of the classes that import the file, it appears that on local servers it works correctly and that publication servers same function fails, I efetuei the test here and with letters in lower case works correctly, however when step to the publishing server has the error occurs, I try to make a simple hotfix and arrange for the CodeIgniter team this week yet

Comment: @Darknessxk interesting.Yeah, I can tell you, I have 3 sites on same server. One is on ver 1.? and works fine with lowercase, the others are on vers 2.2 & 3.0 and are the ones having problems.

Comment: @SpYk3HH is the same with me, i've made a entire new website using 3.0 but all functions filenames with de first letter as uppercase because of this bug

Comment: i almost giving-up setting my CI on live server until i found this answer. thank you very much!